# Compiling a program causes my system to run out of memory, any workarounds?

Tags: linux, memory, cgroups, resources

During the compilation my system runs out of memory on a compilation unit. How can I deal with this issue?

One way is to enable swap but just doing that would make the machine unuable while the program is compiling.

I'm thinking of creating a new user, setting it's home directory same as the current account (for porting over build environment and configuration), set up file permissions as needed, and limit the main memory of this user to 7.5 gb (I've 8 gb of ram). And `su new_user` before doing anything that might use a lot of ram.

I tried using cgroups for this task. This is my `/etc/cgconfig.conf`:

```
group memlimit {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 10m;
    }
}
```

My `/etc/cgrules.conf`:

```
limited memory memlimit
```

I've added this line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet cgroup_enable=memory"
```

But this doesn't seem to work, the new user is still able to eat up all the memory.

How do I limit the main memory available to a user, while keeping the swap memory usage unrestricted?

Are there any other ways of doing this memory hungry task?

Comment: 1. what's worse: out-of-memory errors or occasional slowdowns?    2. is there any reason you can't just add more RAM to the system? memory is pretty cheap these days.  3. is there any way you can break down the problematic part of the source code into smaller pieces that can be compiled separately?

Comment: 1. both are bad, 2. It's a laptop with 8gb max, 3. I'm afraid not, the code is huge and there might be other units giving similar problems

Comment: The linking hasn't even started yet.

Comment: if you can't add more RAM and you can't split the code into smaller compilable units, then your only real choice is to enable swap.   This is useful anyway, so that idle programs and data aren't wasting RAM that could be used for useful tasks (like compiling software).

Comment: Yes I know, I've already done that.

Comment: one other alternative is to use your laptop to ssh into another computer with lots of RAM and compile your code there.    maybe edit the Makefile (or whatever) to create a target that not only compiles the code but installs the binaries into a temp directory and then tars it up for easy download.   or builds an installable package (deb or rpm or whatever).

Comment: Deal with the cause of the problem instead of fighting the symptoms. What is your build system? What is your compiler? What are your compiler options? Switching off a certain optimization flag can drastically reduce memory consumption without noticable performance loss. And keep your build system from starting more processes than it makes sense.